# Как убрать обводку

Tags: html, javascript, css

Появилась вот такая обводка, вокруг блока после того как подключил к блоку вот этот [Vertical Scrolling Using JavaScript | dyn-web.com](http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/vert.php) скролинг . 
В css найти не могу её, а точнее её просто нет. 
Как удалить вот такое?

[image: http://pastexen.com/i/okCsL9uRhi.png]

Comment: >http://pastexen.com/i/okCsL9uRhi.png - не открывается картинка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@RattleSneyk](/users/19483/rattlesneyk)

```
div.holder {
    float:left;
    border:1px dotted #999; /* Вот она */
}
```

Comment: ага. Нашел уже, но спс=)